# Error: Could not find or load main class VScode Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

MY code:

```
package JAVA_PROGRAMS;

public class fibonacci{

public static void main(String args[])
{
    int n1=0,n2=1,n3,i,count=10;

    System.out.print(n1+" "+n2);

    for(i=2;i<count;i++)
    {
        n3=1+n2;
        System.out.print(" "+n3);
        n1=n2;
        n2=n3;
    }
}

}
```

Error :
Error: Could not find or load main class fibonacci
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JAVA_PROGRAMS/fibonacci (wrong name: fibonacci)

Comment: What is the name of the java file?

Comment: Because of the `package` statement, the class is named `JAVA_PROGRAMS.fibonacci`, and if you run with a simple `java JAVA_PROGRAMS.fibonacci` command, then you need file `JAVA_PROGRAMS/fibonacci.class` relative to the current working directory. See duplicate link up top for more information.

Answer (score -1):

This generally happens if you saved your java file with a name that is not the same as the **"public class"** name of your file.

In your case the file should be saved as **'fibonacci.java'**.

And the way you compile it on a terminal is :- **javac fibonacci.java**,  and to run the program you do  **java fibonacci**.

But on vscode you probably just have to hit the "run" button, I am not sure of it as I like working on terminal.

Comment: on terminal it woks fine but while using run the error occurs

Comment: Hmm...strange. So the problem is only with VSCode?, or do you mean that everything is fine up till the compile step and then things are not working? It would be more helpful if you could share the screenshot of your problem through a drive link.

Comment: I moved few programs in the new folder and try to run them but the error occurs as above but simply using the terminal it works fine. Don't know what happened there.

Comment: https://imgur.com/zZZhP9v

Comment: This answer is entirely ignoring the very important effect of the `package JAVA_PROGRAMS;` statement, making the answer useless.